# Add HTML code which change frequently to multiple WordPress pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I want to add a custom made navigation menu to some of the WordPress pages I don't want it on all pages so `header.php` is not an option. The navigation menu will have links to my posts or pages. The navigation menu changes frequently, so if add the HTML directly to my WordPress pages then if I want to change the nav menu, I have to edit all my WordPress pages.

I want to make a javascript file like this which contains some content of the nav menu.

```
var list='<li><span><span><a href="https://codingile.com/c-introduction/">Introduction</a></li>\
<li><span><span><a href="https://codingile.com/variables-identifiers-in-c/">Variables and Identifiers</a></li>\
<li><span><span><a href="https://codingile.com/data-types-in-c/">Data Types</a></li>\
<li><span><span><a href="https://codingile.com/operators-in-c/">Operators</a></li>\
<li><span><span><a href="https://codingile.com/printf-and-scanf-in-c/">printf and scanf</a></li>\
<li><span><span><a href="https://codingile.com/conditional-statements-in-c/">conditional Statements</a></li>\
<li><span><span><a href="https://codingile.com/switch-case-in-c/"> switch statement</a></li>\
<li><span><span><a href="https://codingile.com/loops-in-c/">Loop statements</a></li>';
document.write(name);
```

Then add this to the pages where I want the navigation menu. If it was an offline HTML page I could have used 
 `<script type="text/javascript src="filename.js></script>`
How can do this on WordPress site? Which folder should I upload this JS file to and how can I load it?

Comment: create a custom template and add the following code on it and then you can call this custom template on any WordPress page you wanted to. and the changes you will make on the template will reflect all the pages it has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not easier to add another menu to the pages you want the menu that changes. You can see how that is done in the following link.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

I think this is better for your indexing as well since you are adding links with JavaScript with what you are asking.

Comment: forget about the menu thing. I just want to add a piece of HTML code to many of my WordPress pages without hard coding it on all pages.

Comment: I would not be hardcoded this way because you are creating a new menu which you could edit in Wordpress like any other menu.  look at the awnser by markmoxx he suggested you do the same thing with some code examples you could find on the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this. Create a new page template in your theme by copying `page.php` to `page_with_menu.php`, and put this at the very top of the page:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Page With custom HTML */ ?>
```

...and (assuming you don't want to use WP navigation menus, as you mentioned in a comment) just put the HTML in the page template where you want it to appear.

Then, just choose that template in Page Attributes in the page editor.

If you do want to use WP nav menus to make changing the menu easier, then register your nav menu in your `functions.php`  with this:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_primary_menu' );
function register_primary_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'my-menu-location' );
}
```

And put this in your new page template, where you want the menu to appear:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => my-menu-location'
) );
```